# ¿Como poner las coordenadas de ubicación en una función?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

necesito de su ayuda, estoy trabajando con la Geolocalización API Google v3, estoy uzando la siguiente función para mostrar las cafeterias que se encuentras cerca es de decir en una distancia de 1 kilómetro en forma de circulo, tengo la información de los lugares guardados en una base de datos, me muestra los lugares mas cercanos pero tengo que ingresar yo las coordenadas manualmente, quisiera saber como hacer la función para que tome por defecto las coordenadas de donde me encuentro.... les dejo el codigo que estoy utilizando.

<------ HTML ------->

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h2 class="conoce">¡CAFETERIA MÁS CERCANA!</h2><br>
      <img src="imagenes/ubica.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <?php 
      echo $obj-> ubicacion_cafeteria();
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p id="status">Buscando su localización…</p>  
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

-------- Script -------

```
function success(position) {  
    var status = document.querySelector('#status');  
    status.innerHTML = "¡Su ubicación!";  

    var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');  
    mapcanvas.id = 'mapcanvas';  
    mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';  
    mapcanvas.style.width = '100%';  

    document.querySelector('#map').appendChild(mapcanvas);  

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);  
    var myOptions = {  
        zoom: 15,  
        center: latng,  
        mapTypeControl: false,  
        navigationControlOptions: {style: 
        google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},  
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
   };  
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);  

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
       position: latlng,  
       map: map,  
       title:"Usted está aquí."  
   });  
}  

function error(msg) {  
   var status = document.getElementById('status');  
   status.innerHTML= "Error [" + error.code + "]: " + error.message;   
}  

if (navigator.geolocation) {  
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error,
        {maximumAge:60000, timeout: 4000});  
} else {  
    error('Actualiza el navegador web para usar el API de localización');  
}
```

<------ Función que utilizo ----->

```
public function ubicacion_cafeteria(){
    $sql = "SELECT id_ubicacion, nombre_cafeteria, direccion, correo, 
    telefono, ciudad, enlace,
            (6371 * ACOS( SIN(RADIANS(latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(21.126029)) + COS(RADIANS(longitude - -101.688782)) * 
            COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(21.126029)) ) ) AS distance 
            FROM ubicacion HAVING distance < 1 ORDER BY distance";
    $result = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
    $ubicacion_cafeteria = '';
    $ubicacion_cafeteria.='
        <div class="col-md-7"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
          <div class="fondo">
                <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th><h4 class="datos"> CAFETERIA </h4></th>
                  <th><h4 class="datos"> DIRECCIÒN </h4></th>
                  <th><h4 class="datos"> CORREO </h4></th>
                  <th><h4 class="datos"> TELÉFONO </h4></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
          <tbody>
    ';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ubicacion_cafeteria.='
                  <tr>
                      <td><P>'.utf8_encode($row['nombre_cafeteria']).'</P></td>
                      <td><p>'.utf8_encode($row['direccion']).'</p></td>
                      <td><p>'.utf8_encode($row['correo']).'</p></td>
                      <td><p>'.utf8_encode($row['telefono']).'</p></td>
                  </tr>
        ';
    }
    $ubicacion_cafeteria .'
              </tbody>
                </table>
          </div>
        </div>';
    return $ubicacion_cafeteria;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener las coordenadas del usuario con el [GeoLocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) que Google ofrece. Recuerda especificar el `API_KEY` para poder hacer uso de esta función como lo indica en el ejemplo:

```js
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Estoy utilizando Geolocation API pero me marca mas a menos a un kilómetro de mi ubicación, pero lo que yo quisiera es obtener esas coordenadas dentro de la función que estoy utilizando para que de esta forma pueda obtener yo las cafeterías mas cercanas a mi ubicación, o si hay alguna otra forma de solucionar lo que busco se los agradecería la verdad no se mucho de esto y necesito de su ayuda.... Gracias....

Comment: Para obtener una posición más precisa podés hacer uso del método `watchPosition` el cual actualiza tu ubicación a una más precisa.